# Customize the achart engine pie chart

Tags: android, achartengine

i am using the pie chart from Achart engine library:

now i need some help on the customization.this is my pie chart drawn -

[image]

These are thing which i am trying to customize :

1. applying circular animation to the pie chart.
2. add thin circular border around the chart.
3. as you can see the labels color 1, color 2 are to the left but i need that in center or apply some padding to it.
4. there is a huge space on the top and bottom decrease the space.
5. now the background color is white i need that in some other color.

How to do these changes ,i have tried searching for these in google and made the possible changes that is in the screen shot.

Comment: These should be organized in several questions, not like this a huge one.

Comment: @Dan thanks i have seen your answers for many questions please help on this

Comment: 2 is not yet available. For the others please post separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only answer the first question:

```
renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
```

Make sure you have a recent build of AChartEngine from [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/) or [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/).

For the fifth question do this:

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: thanks i have done that now i have edited my question please help me

Comment: hey i need to display values of slices beside that instead on the slice? how to do that

Comment: and yes i have the latest jar file

Comment: i need your help in editing the source code of achart engine